# I am writing some functions for Strings, but i have a problem with realloc

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I am writing some functions for strings, and im having a problem with realloc. Why do i get the error `realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x000...`

This is my string structure:

```
typedef struct {
    int length;       /* Length of the String excluding '\0' */
    char * string;    /* pointer to string */
} string;
```

This is my string creating function:

```
string string_create(char content[]) {
    string localString;
    localString.length = 0;
    while (content[localString.length] != '\0') {
        localString.length++;
    }
    localString.string = (char *)calloc((localString.length + 1), sizeof(char));
    localString.string = content;
    return localString;
}
```

This is my string insertion function: (The function with the problems)

```
void string_insert(string * btstring, int index, char s[]) {        

    int stringLength = 0;
    while (s[stringLength] != '\0') {
        stringLength++;
    }

    if (stringLength > 0) {
        btstring -> length += stringLength;
        btstring -> string = (char *) realloc((btstring -> string), ((btstring -> length + 1) * sizeof(char)));


        for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
            char c = s[i];
            char temp[2] = {0, c};
            int cindex = index + i;
            while (btstring -> string[cindex] != '\0') {
                temp[0] = btstring -> string[cindex];
                btstring -> string[cindex] = temp[1];
                temp[1] = temp[0];
                cindex++;
            }
            temp[0] = btstring -> string[cindex];
            btstring -> string[cindex] = temp[1];
            temp[1] = temp[0];
            cindex++;
            btstring -> string[cindex] = temp[1];
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: realloc can fail, you have to check the answer.
Don't cast malloc or realloc result

Comment: @Ôrel, not only that, it can return the requested amount of memory _at a different address_.

Comment: How can i avoid casting the pointer, if i dont i get an error

Comment: What has this to do with the c-preprocessor?

Comment: If you get an error when you don't cast, you are compiling as C++, not as C.

Comment: For inserting the string `s` into the string of `btstring` I suggest you take a debugger to step through the code. What you do seems overly complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`realloc` can return the requested amount of memory at a different address (and it can fail). Therefore, you should do:

```
    char *tmp;
    tmp = realloc(btstring->string, stringLength + 1);
    if (!tmp) return;                  // could not allocate the memory
    btstring->string = tmp;            // assign the (new) memory to the string.
    btstring->length = stringLength;   // only now update the length
```

Notes:

- `realloc` retains the data of the original memory if it has to allocate a different piece of memory to satisfy your request.
- don't cast the return value of the `malloc` family of functions. A `void` pointer is compatible with all pointers.
- the size of a char is always 1.
- though a matter of style, it is common not to have spaces between the struct and members as in `a->b` and `c.d`.

---

Another error is in the create function:

```
localString.string = content;
```

This will assign the character pointer `content` to the character pointer `localString.string`, throwing away the memory you just allocated. You should do:

```
strcpy(localString.string, content);
```

This copies the *content* of the string `content` to the memory of `localString.string`.